# name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which is stored in builtins. This is used to load python modules with relative paths from the projects base directory. The projecs base directory is stored under builtins.absolute

Function below:

```
def projectRelativeImport(fileName, projectRelativePath, moduleName = None):
    # if moduleName not set, set it to file name with first letter capatilised
    if moduleName is None:
        moduleName = fileName[:1].capitalize() + fileName[1:]

    # we shouldn't be passing fileName with an extension unless moduleName is set due to previous if. So in those cases we add .py
    if len(fileName) >= 3 and fileName[-3:] != '.py':
        fileName = fileName + '.py'

    dir = os.path.join(builtins.absolute, projectRelativePath)
    full = os.path.join(dir, fileName)

    sys.path.append(dir)
    imp.load_source(moduleName, full)
    sys.path.remove(dir)
```

On one of my other files I use `projectRelativeImport('inputSaveHandler', 'app/util', 'SaveHandler')` to import SaveHandler from app/util/inputSaveHandler.py. This runs through the project RelativeImport absolutely fine. Correct strings are being used by imp, I've printed to check.

But a couple of lines after that execution I have a line

```
handler = SaveHandler.ConfHandler()
```

Which throws `NameError: name 'SaveHandler' is not defined`

---

I realise my project relative import function is a bit odd, especially since I have it globally saved using builtins (there's probably a better way but I only started using python over the last two days). But I'm just a bit confused as to why the name isn't being recognised. Do I need to return something from imp due to scope being rubbish as the project relative import function is in a different file?

Comment: you put a function in `builtins`?! I don't think I'd recommend that.

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to be immediately accessible at the top of any file for imports. If there's another way that would be great. Eventually I hope to have it working similar to namespaces in other languages

Comment: @Shard well, speaking about other languages, even in C++ it's a bad thing to handle namespaces via `using ...{}` in header files (which are the things you "import" from in C/C++). Similarly, in Python you put your functions into modules and import them/from them.

Comment: imports in python don't go to parents. Or siblings. Which is why my method solves this issue, but it can't solve the issue of importing itself so that's why it's like this. Currently there's a launcher.py, with an app directory, storage directory, settings directory. Within app you have a main.py, modules directory and util directory, those two directories in turn contain more files. When one of my modules files needs to access a helper from util they require this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by returning from projectRelativeImport() what was passed back from imp.load_source as shown below:

```
sys.path.append(dir)
submodule = imp.load_source(moduleName, full)
sys.path.remove(dir)
return submodule
```

Then when I used the import function the returned value now goes to a variable with the same name as that I gave to the module (all very strange)

```
SaveHandler = projectRelativeImport('inputSaveHandler', 'app/util', 'SaveHandler')
```

I got to this because it worked no problem from the file projectRelativeImport was defined in but not in any others. So it was clearly a scope issue to me, so I figured I'd just try returning whatever imp gave me and it worked